# php variables to array - opposite of "extract"

Tags: php, arrays, extract

PHP has a function extract that will convert an array like this:

```
$array = array(
 'var1' => 1,
 'var2' => 2
);
```

to:

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
```

now, I need the opposite, i have few variables:

```
$var3 = 'test';
$test = 'another';
$datax = 1;
```

that needs to be:

```
$array = array(
 'var3' => 'test',
 'test' => 'another',
 'datax' => 1
);
```

Is there something like this in PHP?

Comment: If these are global scope, you already have it in `$GLOBALS['test']. $GLOBALS['var3']` [`$GLOBALS` reference](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: It says `compact` right on the [manual page for `extract`](http://php.net/extract). Why didnt you find it?

Comment: The correct answer would be "create a class containing the properties var3, test and datax", but unfortunately in SO perspective that won't be an answer to your question.

Comment: (For beginners wandering here.) No, the "correct" answer to this particular question -- i.e. without being opinionated, or "smart", assuming various background conditions that are not actually present... -- is absolutely *not* to "create a class", or to involve any other concepts or complexities into the problem space that have neither been called for nor necessary. And it has nothing to do with SO (but everything with Occam's razor and general conceptual hygiene). (If the question or the context were about architecture, OOP, or coding best practices etc., CodeCaster would've had a point.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `compact()` to achieve this.

```
$var3 = 'test';
$test = 'another';
$datax = 1;
$array = compact('var3', 'test', 'datax');
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 4):

like this

```
$preDefined = (get_defined_vars());
$var3 = 'test';
$test = 'another';
$datax = "1";
$newDefined = array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $preDefined);
print_r($newDefined);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = get_defined_vars()
```

See [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get-defined-vars)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to be **really** sure you wanted to do this (it includes things in the global scope automatically) but you can use

```
$my_vars = get_defined_vars();
```

If you want it more selective than that, you could look at filtering it like this:

```
$my_vars = pack_vars(get_defined_vars())

function pack_vars ($defined_vars)
{
    $packed = array();
    $ignored = array('dont_use_this', 'ignored_var', 'ignore_this_too');

    foreach ($defined_vars AS $key => $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($key, $ignored))
        {
            $packed[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $packed;
}
```

Comment: Inside of a function get_defined_vars() returns only those variables available in the function.
I have used frameworks previously which expect an array to be returned from the controller. This function is useful. Remember to unset any unwanted variables before using it - such as a database result set.